# Stateful LSTM Model raising InvalidArgumentError in the last step of the first epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to train a Stateful LSTM network. But it shows an error in the last step of the first epoch. The model code is given bellow.

```py
inp = Input(batch_input_shape=(32,X.shape[1]))
features = Embedding(vocab_size, 64)(inp)
lstm1, state_h, state_c = LSTM(512,return_sequences=True,return_state=True,stateful=True)(features)
output = Dense(vocab_size,activation='softmax')(lstm1)

model  = Model(inputs=[inp],outputs=[output,state_h,state_c])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss = [tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)],
              metrics=['accuracy']
             )

history = model.fit(X,Y,epochs=5)
```

Here is a brief part of output log:

```
Epoch 1/5
596/597 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2202 - dense_30_loss: 1.2202 - dense_30_accuracy: 0.7465 - lstm_46_accuracy: 0.0026 - lstm_46_1_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

.....
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 11712 values, but the requested shape has 15616
     [[node gradient_tape/model_26/embedding_42/embedding_lookup/Reshape_1 (defined at <ipython-input-310-03a899ee0bf6>:1) ]]
     [[gradient_tape/model_26/embedding_42/embedding_lookup/Reshape_1/_22]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 11712 values, but the requested shape has 15616
     [[node gradient_tape/model_26/embedding_42/embedding_lookup/Reshape_1 (defined at <ipython-input-310-03a899ee0bf6>:1) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_227344]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

I don't know where I'm wrong. The code works fine when `stateful=False`. For stateful LSTM I had to set `batch_input_shape` instead of `shape` in `Input()` function. Batch size is set to 32 as `model.fit()` automatically takes a batch size 32 by default. Is the problem due to a bug or am I doing it in the wrong way?

Comment: I guess the problem is coming from your trainset. if you write a costume train loop and ignore the last batch, you probably won't have this problem. can you also add the dataset to your question?